# SOAPUI data driven Test Suite, how do I convert the <input> child tag into CDATA?

Tags: groovy, soapui

OK - be gentle with me as I'm not techie

I'm wanting to create a set of data driven tests for a service where both the request and response wrap all the elements into CDATA

So to map the input fields to my data source I've created a request without the CDATA so that I can map every request field to my data source.

But of course, the service is expecting to see these fields in CDATA so the requests fail. I know I need to find a way to convert the mapped fields back to CDATA

Have tried adding a Event, Requestfilter.filterRequest with the following:

```
//This event handler will affect all requests
if( request.requestContent == null )
   return log.info "Old request without CDATA : " + request.requestContent
   def requestContent = request.requestContent

//requestContent = requestContent.replaceAll( "<!\\[CDATA\\[", "" )
//requestContent = requestContent.replaceAll( "]]>", "" )
requestContent = requestContent.replace ( "<Input>" , "<![CDATA[<Input>" )
requestContent = requestContent.replace ( "</Input>" , "</Input>]]>" )
log.info "New request with CDATA : " + request.requestContent
request.requestContent =  requestContent
```

Tried testing this event in a manual test step and  the first call fails with Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Input"). Expected elements are (none)

A second call concatenates the event but actually works ok

A third call concatenates the event and fails with Unmarshalling Error: String ']]>' not allowed in textual content, except as the end marker of CDATA section
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [68,20]

I know I'm close to getting this working so would appreciate some help !

Comment: Can you please show the sample request ? Also would you mind showing what kind of source are you using for data driven test? Are you using ReadyAPI?

Comment: Thanks for replying Rao but I've figured I don't actually need to create this wrapper. I took the CDATA out of the base request so I could map input fields against the datasource. Having done this, I manually the CDATA wrapper to the base request and was delighted to see the datasource mappings remain in the CDATA text. So job done and it's working a treat